# Webpage redirect not working properly

Tags: php, session, redirect

I'm making the index.php page for my website and I've come across multiple errors on line 13 of the code below, but I have fixed the majority of them. I've tried adding

```
</meta>
```

and even the 
    ;
, after
    http-equiv="refresh"

Here's my code:

```
<?php


session_start();


$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$password = $_SESSION['password'];

if(!$username && !$password){

echo "You will be redirected to login in 5 seconds! (<meta http-equiv="refresh"; content="5; URL=login.php"></meta>)";

}else{

echo "Welcome , ".$username."! (<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>)";

}



?>
```

Comment: the problem is the double quote inside your double quote.. escape them using \ or use single quote instead.

Comment: @jaytemp So " echo "You will be redirected to login in 5 seconds! (<meta http-equiv=\"refresh"\; content=\"5; URL=login.php"\></meta>)"; " should work?

Comment: yes that should work, and meta tags are self closing. no need for `</meta>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the double quote inside your double quote.. escape them using \ or use single quote instead.

```
echo "You will be redirected to login in 5 seconds! (<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"; content=\"5; URL=login.php\">)";
```

Comment: It works! Huge thanks man, I'll choose this as the correct answer as soon as it allows me too. :)